# COM+ remoting error code 8000401a because password of This User under Identity tab getting reset

Tags: c#, .net, com, remoting, com+

I am an admin in my COM+ server machine, my COM+ server component identity set to "This User" and provided my credentials there. I could invoke my component from client machine. But client app will stop working after some time with errorcode 8000401a. So I shutdown my server app and when I start the app back it shows an error username and password incorrect with error code 8000401a. When I re-entery my password again and strat it back. it works fine. Seems my password entered in identity tab is being reset? Why?

Comment: Do you have any event log recording around the time you start getting this `CO_E_RUNAS_LOGON_FAILURE`?

Comment: I'd be grateful if you'd accept my answer (assuming it solved your problems)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that your domain account looses its **Log on as a batch job** privilege on every Active Directory resync and the server app is unable to restart afterwards. Re-entering your credentials restores the privilege only temporarily.

You have to permanently give the **Log on as a batch job** privilege to your account via the GPO on the domain controler (see [Q312497](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312497) for the complete description).

I'm not sure why, but I've had a case where the **Log on as a service** privilege was also required (try that as well if the **Log on as a batch job** doesn't do it).

Answer (score 0):

If it's "This User", then check to make sure the user credentials have access to the file system and any binaries needed by the application.

Comment: Yes, user credentials i supplied is of an admin user. Complete access to everything needed by the applciation. Also everything works fine for some time. After say half an hour or so it stops working. I re-enter the password and its starts working again. Something is changing the password after a stipulated time I guess